# How to draw a MKCircle whose fill color is not solid but an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I found out how to draw a cricle around map annotation.
I do it like this:

```
     MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:theCoordinate radius:15000];
     [myMap addOverlay:circle];

 -(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay
 {
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    circleView.fillColor =[UIColor redColor];

   return circleView;
}
```

It works ok but i would like to draw a circle whose fill color is not solid like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To draw a circle with a gradient, you have to provide an own annotation view class, as none of the existing ones support that. What you can do is you can override the method `- (void)fillPath:(CGPathRef)path inContext:(CGContextRef)context` in a subclass of `MKCircleView`. Here is some code (non-optimized, with hardcoded fill parameters) to get you started:

```
@interface TWOGradientCircleView : MKCircleView
@end

@implementation TWOGradientCircleView

- (void)fillPath:(CGPathRef)path inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGRect rect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGFloat gradientLocations[2] = {0.6f, 1.0f};
    // Start color white with 0.25 alpha,
    // End color green with 0.25 alpha
    CGFloat gradientColors[8] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocations, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGPoint gradientCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGFloat gradientRadius = MIN(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, gradientCenter, 0, gradientCenter, gradientRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
```

To use it, just replace `MKCircleView` with `TWOGradientCircleView`:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay
{
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[TWOGradientCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];

    return circleView;
}
```

If you would like to use an image instead of drawing the gradient, you can replace the gradient drawing above with image drawing. As zooming in would then blur the image, you should either disable zoom, or tile the image as Apple demonstrated in a session at WWDC10 (see [here](https://github.com/klokantech/Apple-WWDC10-TileMap) for a repository with their sample code). Setting a `UIColor` with a pattern image does not work for a radius of 15000 (unless you use a really, really huge image ;)).

Comment: you need to replace interface TWOGradientCircleView : MKCircleView with interface TWOGradientCircleView : MKCircleRenderer for this to work on iOS7+ (and iOS8+ is explicitly denied to use MKCircleView)

Answer (score 10):

Answer for iOS 7 using MKCircleRenderer...

You should subclass MKCircleRenderer, and override the `fillPath:inContext` method, similarly to the accepted answer to this question. e.g.

```
@implementation MKGradientCircleRenderer

- (void)fillPath:(CGPathRef)path inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{

    CGRect rect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGFloat gradientLocations[2] = {0.6f, 1.0f};
    // Start color white with 0.25 alpha,
    // End color green with 0.25 alpha
    CGFloat gradientColors[8] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocations, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGPoint gradientCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGFloat gradientRadius = MIN(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, gradientCenter, 0, gradientCenter, gradientRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);


}
```

And then in your MKMapView delegate, implement the following method...

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MKCircle * circle = (MKCircle *)overlay;

    MKGradientCircleRenderer * renderer = [[MKGradientCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:circle];

    return renderer;

}
```

This will allow you to achieve the same effect, but using the new methods available in iOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

To implement the solution in Swift 2.0 (iOS7+) I used the following solution

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class TWOGradientCircleRenderer: MKCircleRenderer {

    override func fillPath(path: CGPath, inContext context: CGContext) {
        let rect:CGRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path)

        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextClip(context);

        let gradientLocations: [CGFloat]  = [0.6, 1.0];
        let gradientColors: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25];
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocations, 2);

        let gradientCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
        let gradientRadius = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2;

        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, gradientCenter, 0, gradientCenter, gradientRadius, .DrawsAfterEndLocation);
    }
}
```

And in your MKMapViewDelegate you will need to add

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            let circleRenderer = TWOGradientCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            return circleRenderer
        } else {
            return MKOverlayRenderer()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the fill colour to a colour created with `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`?

Comment: That would allow to use a pattern, but not the gradient shown in the question. Even if you would store the whole gradient as a bitmap image and convince `UIImage` to make the pattern big enough, zooming in would either lead to a blurry/pixelated overlay, or require a huge overlay image.

Comment: He asked about an image, not a gradient. :)

Comment: :) In the title, in the text it's about drawing a circle.

Comment: It's really up to @DixieFlatline to clarify the question.

Comment: That's right. Could you clarify your answer into a working solution? I tried it before writing up my answer, and it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: If you have a question, you should ask it rather than piggy-backing on another question in comments. That way, other people can see your question separately and provide their own answers.

Comment: Your answer was accepted, but does not provide a working example, and I doubt it works at all for the original question. There is no better point for the clarification than here.

Comment: My answer was not accepted; the bounty ran out because @DixieFlatline did not return to the question. If you have your own question, you should ask it.

Comment: Then be glad that you got 50 points for an answer that does not work. Let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for Swift 3.0 / iOS 10.

```
class CircleRenderer: MKCircleRenderer {
    override func fillPath(_ path: CGPath, in context: CGContext) {
        let rect: CGRect = path.boundingBox
        context.addPath(path)
        context.clip()
        let gradientLocations: [CGFloat]  = [0.6, 1.0]
        let gradientColors: [CGFloat] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.25]
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: colorSpace, colorComponents: gradientColors, locations: gradientLocations, count: 2) else { return }

        let gradientCenter = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let gradientRadius = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 2
        context.drawRadialGradient(gradient, startCenter: gradientCenter, startRadius: 0, endCenter: gradientCenter, endRadius: gradientRadius, options: .drawsAfterEndLocation)
    }
}
```

And the overlay delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let circleRenderer = CircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)

    return circleRenderer
}
```

An example of this at work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

** Only Updating answer:

In IOS 7 fillPath:inContext was deprecated to MKCircleView. Try to use MKCircleRenderer instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayPathRenderer